# Before update post to save value using save_post hook?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Add new product to update product then set sku number permalinks before post title to set in permalinks. Product import then set sku number in permalinks before update product.

I tried the below code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'change_title');

function change_title($post_id) {
  // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
  remove_action('save_post', 'change_title');
  $_sku = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', true);

  $args = array('ID'=>$post_id,'post_name'=>$_sku,);
  // update the post, which calls save_post again
  wp_update_post( $args );

  // re-hook this function
  add_action('save_post', 'change_title');
}
```

Comment: why is this not working?

Comment: why you are removeing the defined hook? `remove_action('save_post', 'change_title');` What do you mean by loop infinitely? This will trigger with a single post or page created or update.

Comment: not add remove action then not work save_post function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I found the given code to be working... problem might exist somewhere else.

Comment: okay..no problem...thanks for suggections and also solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
        function change_title( $post_id ){
          $_sku = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', true);
          global $wpdb;
          $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_title' => $_sku ), array( 'ID' => $post_id ) ); 
        }
        add_action( 'save_post', 'change_title');
```

Comment: thank you for answer.but I have try import product to automatic change before update product how???

Comment: I know that but it's not work import product to set permalinks into http://site-name/product/post-title but update product to set  http://site-name/product/sku number.I have set sku number before update product.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function update_product_link( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
   if( $post->post_type != "product" ) {
      return;
   }
   $_sku = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', true);
   //This will update post name to SKU
   $post->post_name = $_sku;        
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_product_link', 1, 3 );
```

Also set your product permalink base structure to `/product/%postname%/`

Comment: Yes, I have tested it.

Comment: when using `save_post` filter, you need to call `wp_update_post` to update the post...

Comment: The `$post` parameter is passed  by reference, so `$post->post_name = $_sku;` is a valid statement and working, just try yourself.!

Comment: no... it's not passed by reference... there's no `&`, how can it be passed by reference?? the OP's code works... that's I'm asking her why it's not working...

Comment: first add new product to set post_title in product permalinks.how to set $sku in product permalinks to add new product time.